# How can I find and delete all custom layouts after a certain layout in PowerPoint?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am migrating a lot of old presentations to a new design using VBA. I have created the new file from a template, copied each slide across and applied the correct custom layout that I need to each one. Once done, I am left with a load of the old custom layouts that are not used, and want to delete them all. The new design uses 50 custom layouts. Is there a way to find the ones after that 50 and delete them? Or delete all layouts after a layout of a specific name?
Here is the code I'm using at the moment. This doesn't remove them all, for some reason. Any help is welcome.

```
    Dim colUsedLayouts As New Collection

For Each sld In NewPres.Slides
    colUsedLayouts.Add sld.CustomLayout
Next

Dim UsedLayout As CustomLayout
Dim LayoutHasBeenUsed As Boolean
Dim EndPointLogoFound As Boolean
For Each lay In NewPres.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts

    If Trim(LCase(lay.name)) = "blank no logo" Then 'Used the else statement so it doesn't delete the Blank No logo layout
        EndPointLogoFound = True
    Else
        If EndPointLogoFound Then
            LayoutHasBeenUsed = False
    
            For Each UsedLayout In colUsedLayouts
                If UsedLayout Is lay Then
                    LayoutHasBeenUsed = True
                End If
            Next
    
            If Not LayoutHasBeenUsed Then
                lay.Delete
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerPoint doesn't really track the order of slide layouts, so trying to delete layouts *after* a certain one isn't reliable. I would go by the layout name. Create a Select Case statement based on the layout name. In the first Case statement, place the names of all 50 good layouts. This Select Case statement will have no commands. Then create a Case Else statement that deletes any layout not found in in the first:

```
Select Case lay.name
    Case "Title Slide", "Title and Content", "Comparison" 'etc. place all 50 names
        'do nothing
    Case Else
        lay.Delete
End Select
```

Comment: Hi John, this is probably the best answer so far, but we have found that once the process is over, and we have tried a few methods, PowerPoint holds on to most of the layouts until the file is saved. It then clears away the deleted layouts, which is not helpful. Oddly, a few remain. We can't see why.

Comment: Sorry, I can't duplicate that result here. Deleting a layout in VBA results in it disappearing immediately. Is there a possibility that the stubborn layouts are actually used by a slide? PowerPoint normally doesn't allow layout deletion for layouts that are in use.

Comment: Interesting. I always get a couple left over. None of the few remaining layouts are assigned to a slide. There are usually just two or three left in the list. In tests, in the immediate window, it doesn't see those left over layouts on the way through. We are seeing if those layouts are being skipped over.

Answer (score 0):

When deleting things from a collection (slides, shapes, layouts, whatever), you need to step through the collection in reverse order otherwise you end up with this situation:

You delete the first one.
The second item in the collection is now item 1, so when you move to the second item and delete it, you're actually deleting what WAS item 3, leaving what WAS item 2 alone.

Instead:

```vb
For x = Collection.Count to 1 step -1
   Collection(x).Delete
Next
```

In this case, you'd use Designs in place of Collection.

Comment: This is a good point. We'll look at this.

Answer (score 0):

This macro deletes any unused custom layouts in a presentation, provided they are not set to "Preserved":

```
Sub RemoveUnusedCustomLayouts(newPres As Presentation)

On Error GoTo RemoveUnusedCustomLayouts_Error

Dim oLayout As CustomLayout
Dim tLayout As CustomLayout
Dim oSld As Slide
Dim delLayoutCnt As Integer
Dim delLayoutArray() As CustomLayout

Dim layoutUsed As Boolean


Dim i As Integer

delLayoutCnt = 0

' We're assuming the deck only has one slide master.
' This sub is only called by other subs that have already
' collapsed the deck into one slide master.

ReDim delLayoutArray(newPres.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts.Count)

For Each oLayout In newPres.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts
    
    layoutUsed = False
    
    If oLayout.Preserved = msoFalse Then
    
        ' Can't delete a layout if it's in use, so we check
        ' for that and add any unused, un-preserved layouts
        ' to Delete array.
        For Each oSld In newPres.Slides
            If oSld.CustomLayout.Name = oLayout.Name Then
                layoutUsed = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        
        If layoutUsed = False Then
            delLayoutCnt = delLayoutCnt + 1
            Set delLayoutArray(delLayoutCnt) = oLayout
        End If
        
    End If
Next

If delLayoutCnt > 0 Then
    For i = 1 To delLayoutCnt
        Set tLayout = delLayoutArray(i)
        tLayout.Delete
    Next
End If
     

On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub

RemoveUnusedCustomLayouts_Error:

Debug.Print "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure RemoveUnusedCustomLayouts, line " & Erl & "."

End Sub
```

Every CustomLayout in a Design must have a unique name (this is why you'll often see "Title and Content_2" in a bloated deck), so checking against the CustomLayout name is the best way to get at the ones you want to delete.

Comment: Hi. We can't delete all the unused layouts, because the template has a range of options for the user. Many of these would also be deleted with the above code. We only want to delete the unused layout AFTER a certain layout in the template.